# You need MANAGE_USERS permission. Getting this exception in fcm in android version 7 and above

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

FirebaseMessagingService: Exception: You need MANAGE_USERS permission to: check if specified user a managed profile outside your profile group getting this exception in fcm while app in background in android version 7 and above its working in 5 and 6 version of android.